# how to find all possible partitions of a set in c++

Tags: c++

how to write a c++ code that finds all possible combination of a set with any size
for an example :

```
set = {a,b,c,d}
```

then the  output of the code must be :

```
 { {a}, {b}, {c}, {d} }
 { {a, b}, {c}, {d} }
 { {a, c}, {b}, {d} }
 { {a, d}, {b}, {d} }
 { {b, c}, {a}, {d} }
 { {b, d}, {a}, {c} }
 { {c, d}, {a}, {b} }
 { {a, b}, {c, d} }
 { {a, c}, {b, d} }
 { {a, d}, {b, c} }
 { {a, b, c}, {d} }
 { {a, b, d}, {c} }
 { {a, c, d}, {b} }
 { {b, c, d}, {a} }
 { {a, b, c, d} }
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: i tried using for loops with conditions but it does not produce all the sets . 
i think the answer to my problem is by using recursive function and i am not good at implementing recursive

Answer (score 1):

Rearranging your answer to put `a` first and sort them by the size of the first element:

```
 { {a}, {b}, {c}, {d} }
 { {a}, {b}, {c, d} }
 { {a}, {b, c}, {d} }
 { {a}, {b, d}, {c} }
 { {a}, {b, c, d} }
 { {a, b}, {c}, {d} }
 { {a, c}, {b}, {d} }
 { {a, d}, {b}, {c} }
 { {a, b}, {c, d} }
 { {a, c}, {b, d} }
 { {a, d}, {b, c} }
 { {a, b, c}, {d} }
 { {a, b, d}, {c} }
 { {a, c, d}, {b} }
 { {a, b, c, d} }
```

And here is the answer for `{b, c, d}`

```
 { {b}, {c}, {d} }
 { {b}, {c, d} }
 { {b, c}, {d} }
 { {b, d}, {c} }
 { {b, c, d}}
```

Now you can see a way of combining `a` with the elements from the `{b,c,d}` answer, which gives you a recursive solution.

Implementation left as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there are 2^n possible combinations you can have with n elements. So you count a loop variable to 2^n and check with a the bitflag (1 << j) if you should include the jth element of the set in that iteration. Note that this implementation only works for sets of size N where 2^N-1 fits into unsigned long long.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> values{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

  const auto size = 1ULL << (values.size());
  std::cout << "{\n";
  for(auto i = 0ULL; i < size; ++i) {
    std::cout << '{';
    for(auto j = 0U; j < values.size(); ++j) {
      if(i & (1ULL << j)) {
        std::cout << values[j] << ',';
      }
    }
    std::cout << "},\n";
  }
  std::cout << "}\n";
}
```

Comment: the question says combinations, the title partitions, this gives you the combinations